# How can I add configurations to cinder.conf at the end of the file using JUJU?

Tags: juju, openstack

I installed Ubuntu OpenStack with Autopilot and I integrated a HP SAN with the lefhand driver. For that, I defined the parameters in config-flags (string) at juju cinder config charm, that place the settings at the default section o cinder.conf. It connects with the san fine, but when I try to attach a volume it fails.

I manually moved the settings to the end of cinder.conf and works fine. Is there any way to do this directly from JUJU? or What option would you recommend me?

Regards

Comment: The [config-flags][1] are inserted before the definition of the backends as it can be checked in the [template][2], so probably that's interfering in your case, maybe the config-flags should be always inserted at the end of the DEFAULT section, not sure about the implications of that change

  [1]: https://jujucharms.com/cinder/trusty#charm-config-config-flags
  [2]: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openstack-charmers/charms/trusty/cinder/trunk/view/head:/templates/kilo/cinder.conf#L48